# Dynamic tracking precision of UR5/10

Tags: dynamics, errors

I am willing to use a universal robot arm (UR10) in a path following mode. i.e. I have a desired trajectory for the robot's effector and I would like the effector to follow it as close as possible.

[The specs here](http://media1.limitless.dk/UR_Tech_Spec/UR10_GB.pdf) give a repeatability of +-0.1mm. This is not written but *I guess* this is the **static precision** (after the robot had enough time to converge to the position). Now what about the **dynamic precision** (i.e. max position error while performing the desired trajectory)?

Does anyone know more than me on this matter?

Kind regards,

Antoine.

Answer (score 1):

I've got two Universal Robots guys in the room with me here, so I asked them this question.

When the robot's performing a Trajectory move (e.g. linear move) then the dynamic precision is the same as the static precision (±0.1mm). The robot would need to be set up correctly, and know the weight of its payload, so it can correctly balance itself.

When the robot's performing a Joint move, where you simply command each joint to move to a certain angle, then precision is obviously irrelevant, since the trajectory is unknown.

Comment: Wow this is _farmer's stack exchange_: fresh from the producers... well except this its not fruits and veggies that we deal with, but answers;) Thanks a lot Rocketmagnet, this helps!